# How to define a Vue transition lifecycle hook within a component for the end of a Router transition?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue (2.6.12) router setup with a standard nav menu on the left side of the page. When I change the route, the current main page content transitions out (with a fade-slide) and the new route component transitions in (for what it's worth, I'm also using the Vuetify UI library, but it shouldn't have any bearing on the problem).

Is there a callback function that can run after the transition of the incoming component has completed? The `mounted` lifecycle hook of the component appears to run before or at the same time as the incoming component is beginning to animate (which makes sense since the component is obviously built and available at that stage). I would like to run some code after the transition has completed. For example, my main component where the routes are handled looks like:

```
<v-main>
  <transition name="content-toggle" mode="out-in">
    <router-view />
  </transition>
</v-main>
```

I've tried adding `v-on:after-enter="doIt"`into my transition above, and then adding the following to my main component:

```
methods: {
  doIt(el) {
    console.log('doing it...', el);
  },
},
```

...and that does fire when I want it to, at the end of the incoming transition, but I need the hook to be defined in the incoming component itself. Is it possible to accomplish that?

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding a ref to your "incoming component" and then call a method from it like $refs.component.doIt() ? Then you could call it from the v-on:after-enter

Comment: @StasParshyn I understand about refs and how to add one to the component, but not sure about the rest of the suggestion. Could you maybe provide some brief snippets that would illustrate the solution?